# Question about Java namespaces for github projects: on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, off-topic

Is the following question too localized for StackOverflow?

> What should be the namespace for my new project hosted at https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/bananator ? I think that according the the Java convention it should be `org.github.nicolas-raoul.bananator` but it is very long and including your own name sounds presumptuous/non-collaborative for Java coders... is there an applicable convention?

I fear that the question would be closed because it is not directly programming.

Is it on-topic or off-topic for StackOverflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely off topic for Stack Overflow. It *might* be on topic on Programmers, but:

1. You really need to show that you did some minimal research, for example you could check how other projects are handling this.
2. "sounds presumptuous" needs to go away, "non-collaborative" needs to be backed up, even if only by a small elaboration on why you think so.

...and you can't use the "a mod said it's ok to post here" argument, I'm not 100% sure, if you decide to post the community will decide if it's on topic or not. All I can say is I wouldn't close the question, and would comment asking clarifications on the two points I've made above.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Indeed it's a risky/subjective, and my questions on Programmers always get downvoted, so I will just use `com.github.bananator`, even though it creates the possibility of a collision.